# using asp.net membership provider in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

im trying to build a DLL which gets parameters (username, password, email). The DLL should add a user to my asp.net database tables through the use of the membership library.

I created a class library and added a console application to the solution. I added a reference from the class library to the console application. But when i try to run the console application it says that the type or namespace  could not be found.....

Here you can find the example project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2266219/ASPBenutzer.zip .

When i delete the function ErstelleBenutzer which uses the Membership library, my test programm (using addition) works...

Maybe you have an idea?

Regards,
float

Comment: What exception and stack trace are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the correct configuration is in your app.config file. (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556567/using-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-dll/4565822#4565822))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MembershipConnectionString" connectionString="connectionstringdetails" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="DefaultSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add reference to System.Web from your console app.

Comment: I have tried it. System.Web doesn't show up under assemblies. But it's referenced in the class library.

Comment: The Problem was the Properties of the Framework. It has to be .NET Framework 4 and not .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. Now i can add System.Web and System.Web.Security.